# Derivative of scalar function with respect to matrix with vectors involved

Tags: matrix-calculus

I want to find derivative of a scalar function with respect to matrix $A$:

$
E=\|f(Ax)\|^2
$

Where $f(Ax)$ is a vector, say color of pixel at position $Ax$. How can I do that, given that I can compute derivative of $f$ with respect to its argument $\partial{f}/\partial{x}$?

I know that I can rewrite function $E$ like this

$
E=f(Ax)^Tf(Ax)
$

or

$
E=tr(f(Ax)f(Ax)^T)
$

Is there a way to find derivative using matrix-vector operations? E.g. without computing derivatives with respect to individual matrix elements. Is there a general analog of chain rule? Say for $g(f(Ax))$, where g is scalar and f is vector.

Comment: Yes. It's called the Matrix Cookbook. Start reading around page 8. https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: @CarlHeckman I've already studied cookbook and did a lot of matrix calculus in the past, yet I don't see pretty solution.

Comment: I wasn't sure by your post. And yes, it does become nasty, because you get $\delta A$ and $(\delta A)^\top$ in your answer ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For convenience, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
 y &= Ax,\,\,\,f = f(y),\,\,\, J = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cr
}$$
Then write the function in terms of the [Frobenius (:) Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product) and take its differential
$$\eqalign{
 E &= f:f \cr\cr
dE &= 2f:df \cr
   &= 2f:J\,dy \cr
   &= 2f:J\,dA\,x \cr
   &= 2J^Tfx^T:dA \cr
}$$
Since $dE = \big(\frac{\partial E}{\partial A}:dA\big),\,$ the gradient must be 
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial E}{\partial A} &= 2\,J^Tfx^T \cr
}$$